# Demoted domain controller and now IIS has permissions issues

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, iis

I have a machine that was a domain controller and everything else, includin an IIS site. I built new 2 new domain controllers and transferred the FSMO roles and waited a day and then demoted the original domain controller. Now the IIS site says :

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
>   You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

I have a call in with the web app vendor, but maybe someone can guess what I need to fix now. I haven't looked at IIS since this was installed and am pretty lost.

I thought about restoring the machine from a backup, but I think that would be an Active Directory disaster, right?

The server is Windows 2008 (not R2). The new DCs are 2008 R2

Comment: Actually, having re-read your question, are the new DCs part of the same domain as the old one?

Comment: @ChrisMcK yes, same domain

Comment: In that case it may be a similar problem related to the IUSR account - did you enable Anonymous authentication when you installed IIS on the new DCs? I'll edit my response accordingly

Comment: IIS is not installed on the new DCs. Just on the old one I demoted.

Comment: In that case try removing/readding the anonymous authentication subfeature.

Comment: Did I understand correctly: IIS is on the 'old' DC that was demoted, and it is still there just that server is not DC anymore? If so, is IIS server still member of the domain?

Comment: @dusan.bajic yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess...

Domain controllers have no local users and groups - they're all held in Active Directory.

When you installed IIS on the DC, it would have created an IUSR account for anonymous access to the sites. This would have been stored in AD and likely was deleted when you demoted it.

Now that the DC has been demoted, the IUSR account is no longer valid. You'll need to re-create the anonymous internet user account. It might actually be easier to back the sites up and remove/reinstall IIS.

Edit: You may need to enable Anonymous Authentication on the new 2008 DCs in the IIS features.

Comment: I would backup the sites and reinstall the OS.

Comment: I'm hoping to not need to reinstall the OS because of all the other stuff running on it. I'm about to get yelled at for this site being down. Oops.

Comment: There really shouldn't be any need for DC restore or OS reinstall. Just follow Chris' advice and set proper user account for IIS

Answer (score 0):

The person is correct, DC's "don't have local accounts while a DC".  When you dcpromo'd down the box, local users were available, you might need to set the IUSR account in the anonymous authentication module.  The error you are seeing is because no authentication providers are enabled.